# Unable to compile Rust 0.9 on OS X

Tags: macos, rust

I want to compile Rust 0.9 on OS X as [explained in the documentation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/0.10). Unfortunately it fails during configuration.

```
$ ./configure   <--------- fails here
$ make && make install
```

With the following error:

```
configure: CFG_PERL             := /usr/bin/perl 
configure: CFG_CURLORWGET       := /usr/bin/curl (curl 7.43.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.43.0 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5)
configure: CFG_PYTHON           := /usr/bin/python2.7 
configure: CFG_GIT              := /usr/bin/git (git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55))
configure: git: no git directory. disabling submodules
configure: CFG_CLANG            := /usr/bin/clang++ (Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn))
configure: CFG_CCACHE           :=  
configure: CFG_GCC              := /usr/bin/gcc (Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn))
configure: CFG_LD               := /usr/bin/ld
configure: on OS X 10.9, forcing use of clang
configure: 
configure: CFG_ENABLE_CLANG     := 1 
configure: error: bad CLANG version: 3.6.0svn, need >=3.0svn
```

When I run the version check for `clang` on my box, I see that I have a higher version:

```
~/Downloads/rust-0.10$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
```

I'm confused as it seems that "3.6.0svn" should satisfy "need >=3.0svn".

Comment: Why... would you want to do this? The current version of Rust is 1.5.0 and contains **numerous** improvements / updates / bug fixes. That is the version that any user should be using.

Comment: Additionally, Rust 0.9 is over two years old at this point...

Comment: I'm trying to get some code up and running https://github.com/ongardie/availsim/tree/d1f120170d4dc6887b002bfbea8543e7a354dca2 and it was developed against Rust v0.9 . If i try to compile with the latest I need to make a bunch code changes which is gonna take longer not being a rust ninja

Comment: If you just want to see a Rust implementation of the Raft algorithm, I'd encourage you to check out [raft-rs](https://github.com/Hoverbear/raft-rs) instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the [`configure` script](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0.10/configure#L613), you will see:

```sh
case $LLVM_VERSION in
    (3.[2-5]*)
        msg "found ok version of LLVM: $LLVM_VERSION"
        ;;
    (*)
        err "bad LLVM version: $LLVM_VERSION, need >=3.0svn"
        ;;
esac
```

This restricts the version of LLVM. It's *possible* you can update it to include 3.6. However, it's also possible that LLVM changed enough between those versions that it wouldn't actually properly link.

Rust proper started supporting 3.6 in [commit 8c3db5bc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/8c3db5bc532f0386f9ceb6d6e26cbcd54d428c5f/configure#L710), *6 months* after Rust 0.9 was released.

I wouldn't be surprised if you stumbled across more and more strange build failures; building code is a tenuous thing.